Nextjs Post to Twitter (X) and upload media on Auth2
I have successfully implemented authentication in my Next.js application to post to X (formerly Twitter) using OAuth2 with access and refresh tokens.
However, I am currently facing challenges when trying to upload media alongside my tweets.

Current Setup
Authentication: Completed using OAuth2.
Posting Text: I can post text-only tweets without any issues.

The Problem
I need guidance on how to upload media using the Twitter API. It seems that:
The media upload requires OAuth1.0a (API v1.1).
The actual posting of tweets can be done using OAuth2 (API v2).
Attempts Made
I have tried implementing OAuth1.0a for media uploads, but this led to errors, specifically stating that I do not have access to the required routes. This has been frustrating since the OAuth2 experience is significantly smoother.
Questions
Is it necessary to authenticate users twice (once for OAuth2 and once for OAuth1.0a) to achieve this?
Can anyone provide a clear example or process on how to upload media using API v1.1 and then post a tweet with that media ID using API v2?
Are there any workarounds or best practices for managing both authentication flows without requiring users to log in multiple times?
References
I found some discussions online, but they often lead back to outdated methods or unclear solutions:
Stack Overflow Discussion
Can I post images/media using Twitter's API
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated! This format clearly outlines your problem, provides context, and directly asks for help, making it easier for others to understand your situation and respond effectively.
